# Correct way to handle pagination with form submission?

Tags: pagination, flask, wtforms

I have a form for doing a search on a search page:

```
<form action="{{ url_for('searchresults') }}" method="get" name="noname" id="theform">
    {{ form2.page(id="hiddenpage") }}
    ... some form inputs
    <button id = "mybutton" type = "submit" >Apply</button>
</form>
```

The form is a `SearchForm`, where

```
class SearchForm(Form):
    page = HiddenField()
    categories = SelectMultipleField(u'Text', validators=[Optional()])
    # some other stuff...
```

The view for `searchresults` handles the form:

```
@app.route('/searchresults', methods=['GET'])
def searchresults():
    form = SearchForm()
    # handle the form and get the search results using pagination
    page = int(request.args.getlist('page')[0])
    results = models.Product.query....paginate(page, 10, False)
    return render_template('searchresults.html', form=form, results=results, curpage=page)
```

The `results` in `render_template` will be the first 10 results of my query. In `searchresults.html` I display the results, along with a `next` and `previous` link for the other results. This page also contains the same search form which I re-instate as per the initial submission. Currently I'm handling the `next` and `previous` links using

```
<a href="#" onclick="$('#hiddenpage').val( {{ curpage+1 }} ); $('#theform').submit();"> Next </a>
```

So the `next` link re-submits the same initial form, but with the `page` value increased. I'm not really happy with this approach because when I hover over the `next` link I don't see the actual page I will be directed to. It also is starting to feel like a bit of a hack. Is there a more natural way to do this? When the form is initially submitted I could use it to create a long string of the desired parameters and use that string in the rendered page as `href=" {{ url_for('searchresults') }}?mystring"`, but this also seems unnatural. How should I handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have your form configured to submit as a `GET` request, so you don't really need to force a re-submission through Javascript, you can achieve the same result by setting the `next` and `prev` links to URLs that include all the parameters in your form with the page modified to the correct next and previous page numbers.

This is really easy to do with `url_for()`. Any argument you add that do not match route components will be added to the query string, so you can do something like this:

```
<a href="{{ url_for('searchresults', categories=form.categories.data, page=form.page.data+1) }}"> Next </a>
```

One thing to keep in mind is CSRF. If you have it enabled in your form, then your next/prev URLs will also need to have a valid token. Or you can disable CSRF, which for a search form might be okay.

Comment: Hi Miguel. Thanks for your answer. This looks like a better approach. It leads me to two questions that I have been wondering about for a while, but this brings them to the forefront. 1) Is clicking on your `Next` link equivalent to submitting a GET form with `categories` and `page` data? I know the resulting URLs will end up looking the same, but is anything else technically different? 2) Why is CSRF important here? I have been inserting ` {{ form.hidden_tag() }}` in my forms without really understanding how they implement some form of safety. How do I give the  next/prev URLs a valid token?

Comment: 1) a form that is submitted as a `GET` request is identical to a regular link that includes all the fields of that form. If you have the `hidden_link` field in this form, then your request includes a CSRF token (which you can see if you look at the URL that is set to your server when you submit a search). 2) I don't think CSRF is important for this case, because the request cannot modify anything in your server. I would just disable it for this form.

Comment: An attacker may want to take advantage of your logged in state to do some operation without your permission. If all this search form does is read some data and return it, and the data is not user sensitive, then CSRF is not necessary. If the data is sensitive, then maybe you should consider  switching to a `POST` request. In this case you can keep the page number in the URL, and only submit the search params in the form.

Answer (score 0):

Take advantage of the fact that your form arguments are already present in the URL and use `request.args` to pass the URL parameters into your form:

```
form = SearchForm(request.args)
```

Then, if you make your `page` field an [`IntegerField`](http://wtforms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/fields.html#wtforms.fields.IntegerField) with a [`HiddenInput`](http://wtforms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/widgets.html#wtforms.widgets.HiddenInput) widget instead of a string field:

```
from wtforms.widgets import HiddenInput

class SearchForm(Form):
    page = HiddenField(widget=HiddenInput, default=1)
```

you can increment `page` before you pass the form off to your search results page:

```
form.page.data += 1
```

And then, in your page, you simply create the link to the next page:

```
<a href="{{ url_for('searchresults', **form.data) }}">Next</a>
```