# Flask pagination, modify request.args or request.form parameters and pass modified values to create new URLs

Tags: python, forms, web, flask, request

Using `url_for('search', **request.form)`, able to send previous form data to new page link, but unable to edit one of the hidden form parameter`request.args.get('page')` to new value (next page number).

As per my current understanding, this [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28132465/correct-way-to-handle-pagination-with-form-submission/28144351?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C121.6636#28144351) answer suggests it is possible to update previous form values, and pass them into pagination links using `url_for`. But while doing so, getting error `AttributeError: 'ImmutableMultiDict' object has no attribute 'page'`. But [request.args](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/0.16.x/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.MultiDict) show some methods like `add` and `setlist(key, new_list)`.

Is it possible to edit and update request.arg or request.form parameters directly and pass them to url_for() with new values, without using Session, Form Rewriting or any pagination library?

```
@app.route('/search', methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def video_search():
   # able to read request.args / request.form parameters here
   # can we edit them ?
   # error request.args.page.data += 1
   # error request.form.page.data += 1
   url_for('search', **request.form)
   return content
```